# Formulario con el post

Tags: laravel, formularios, controller

estoy trabajando con laravel 6.0, realice un formulario con el metodo post y cuando doy en el submit no me permite volver a la pagina que deseo mostrandome el siguiente cartel :
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
http://localhost/laravel/public/computadoras/new

En la vista

```
<form action="{{url('/computadoras')}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <div class="marca">
       <label for="marca">{{'Marca'}}</label>
       <input type="text" name="marca" id="marca">
    </div>
       <div class="nroinv">
           <label for="marca">{{'Número de inventario'}}</label>
           <input type="text" name="nroinv" id="nroinv">
       </div>
       <div class="sn">
           <label for="sn">{{'Número de serie'}}</label>
           <input type="text" name="sn" id="sn">
       </div>
       <input type="submit" value="Agregar">
   </form>
```

y en el controlador los metodos crear y storage

```
public function create()
{
    $computadoras= Computadora::all();
    return view('computadoras/computadorasnew', ['computadoras' => $computadoras]);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request  $request)
{
    // Instancio al modelo Jugos que hace llamado a la tabla 'jugos' de la Base de Datos
    $computadora = new Computadora();
    // Recibo todos los datos del formulario de la vista 'computadorasnew.blade.php'
    $computadora->nombre = $request->get('marca');
    $computadora->precio = $request->get('nroinv');
    $computadora->stock = $request->get('sn');

    // Inserto todos los datos en mi tabla 'computadoras'
    $computadora->save();
    // Hago una redirección a la vista principal con un mensaje
    return redirect('/computadoras')->with('message','Guardado Satisfactoriamente !');
    //return "Guardado existoso";
}
```

estos son los unico metodos que tengo implementado en mi controlador,seria de mucha ayuda cualquier opinion

Comment: Prueba agregando a tu formulario la directiva `@method('POST')`

Comment: Publicá tu archivo de rutas, el problema seguro está ahí.

Comment: Gracias fue util su ayuda